# Retrieve specific value inside array from json response in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I need to get the value of `id`inside `student`array. The response I get is,

```
{
  "response": {
      "student": [
        {
           "id": "125745",
           "module": 3,
           "status": 1
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

I tried using following code,

```
        String userId = null;
        try {
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();

            userId= object.getString("id");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it doesn't work. How do I retrieve `id`?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just you need to do this:

```
JSONArray students = object.getJSONArray("student");
JSONObject student = students.getJSONObject(0);
userId= student.getString("id");
```

Because the id value is placed in a JSONObject, then inside a JSONArray at index 0, then it is again placed inside a JSONObject.

Also don't forget to handle exceptions, the code above, is just for your understanding.

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Your value is placed in json array. So, you need to retrieve `response` object using `getJSONObject` and then get `student` json array via `getJSONArray`. Then you will be able to iterate through `student` objects. There is no way to magically get id from json. 
Alternatively, you can map your json to Java objects using Gson, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Let all of the json is called

```
String serverResponse = "Response from the server";
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(serverResponse);
    String userId = object.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("student").getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
    }
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming jsonObject is a reference to your root json, you can get id of the first student:

```
JSONObject response = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response");
JSONArray students = (JSONArray) response.get("student");
int id = (int) ((JSONObject)students.get(0)).get("id");
```